# Wait for a particular image to load completely using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently using the code below to load images but I want to show some kind of loading gif before the image loads completely.

```
$('#addimage').attr('src', src[i]);
$('#addimage').show();
```

Since I am using this in a animated mediabox the image loading in blocks does not look good so by the time the image is loading I want to replace it by showing a loading gif. Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) event:

```
$("#addimage").load(function() {
  $(this).show();
});
```

**Edit:** to show one image until another loads is a little more convoluted but entirely possible. See [Image Loading](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/image-loading/).

Comment: @halocursed: added a link to what you want.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the callback event for once the image has loaded. Something like:

```
$('#addimage').load(function() { $(this).show() });
$('#addimage').attr('src', src[i]);
```

So you setup the load handler first, then apply your src attribute. This is assuming the image is hidden by default (via CSS, etc).

Answer (score 3):

You can bind the `onload` event to the image.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set the src attribute to point to a loading image (EG, animated gif) and just show it the whole time?