# Swap images with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have several articles on the webpage and each article has a main image and some buttons to load and swap the main image. The problem with my jQuery script below is that it affects all main images inside all articles, I just want to swap the main images within in the article where i click on it's button. Is this possible?

HTML (I have several articles like this on the webpage) :

```
<article class='post'>
<header><h2>Metropolis</h2></header>
<img src='images/buildings/large/metropolis-1.jpg' alt='Metropolis Köpenhamn' class='postImg mainImage' >
<div class='infoContainer'>
<div class='buttonContainer'>
<ul>
<li><a href='images/buildings/large/metropolis-1.jpg' >1</a></li>
<li><a href='images/buildings/large/metropolis-2.jpg' >2</a></li>
<li><a href='images/buildings/large/metropolis-2.jpg' >3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class='plus'><img src='images/icons/arrow-down.png'></div>
</article>
```

jQuery:

```
    $(".buttonContainer ul li a").click(function(event) {
    $(".loader").show();
    var btnNum = $(".buttonContainer a").index(this);
    var btnUrl = $(this).attr("href");
    var imgNew = $("<img />").attr("src", btnUrl).load(function() {
        $(".mainImage").attr("src", imgNew.attr("src"));
    $(".loader").hide();
    });
     return false;
});
```

Comment: its like ,if I click on an "a" tag ,the "main image" should change  to the one in the "href" of " a " tag right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".buttonContainer ul li a").click(function(event) {
 var btnUrl = $(this).attr("href");
 $(this).parents(".post").find(".mainImage").attr("src",btnUrl);
});
```

> **Updated**

**Edit**(unchecked)

```
  $(".buttonContainer ul li a").click(function(event) {
 var btnUrl = $(this).attr("href");
  $(".loader").show();
  $(this).load(function{ $(".loader").hide();});
 $(this).parents(".post").find(".mainImage").attr("src",btnUrl);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't working! I have several articles and each articles has it's own image and buttons to change the image within a article. Your code affect all images in all articles!

Comment: I updated my question and I think the code I have added to my question is enough.

Comment: Yes, that work much better! But how could this work without the .load function?

Comment: changing the src with attr function will change the image dynamically.

Comment: OK, but I guess I need the function to use spinning animation while it's loading like this: $(".loader").show(); and when it has been loaded like this: $(".loader").hide(); I'm trying to do that with your code.

Comment: see this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129392/wait-for-a-particular-image-to-load-completely-using-jquery

Comment: I know that you already has answered my question, but could you also help me to add the show and hide part in your answer?

Comment: check the new update and comment me , I didn't checked it .

Comment: Thanks for your update! I will try that code tomorrow, it's getting late here! I will accept your answer despite if yor update will work or not work, since you have solved the main problem. I should have the load and hide part from the beginning of my question. But I removed that to simplify the code.

Comment: Why do You hide and show the .mainImage? I made a small update to my question an added the hide and show code. I guess the return false part is importand because without that the image will be opened in the webpage without all previous HTML-code.

Comment: do you mean the loader image ?

Comment: No, I mean the $(".mainImage").hide(); and $(".mainImage").show();

Comment: can we chat  , since I didn't the last part ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107285/discussion-between-sachin-and-3d-kreativ).